# Include Excel table in the body of an email in Python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Using Python, I am trying to send an email with an Excel table inside the body of an email. I would like to maintain all the conditional formatting from the Excel file. I can send the Excel file as an attachment easy, but I would like to also put the table inside the body of the email.  I will convert it to an HTML table if I need to, but I need to know how to include the HTML table into body of the email then. Below attaches the file as an email, but I haven't been able to figure out how to put the table inside of the email. How can I do this?

```
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['Subject'] = 'Subject goes here'
msg.attach(MIMEText('Text goes here'))
part = MIMEBase('application', "octet-stream")
f = 'file_name.xlsx'
part.set_payload(open(f, "rb").read())
encoders.encode_base64(part)
part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="%s"' % f)
msg.attach(part)
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You should look up documentation on add mime parts to e-mails.

Comment: @Emac - Did you manage to solve this? I am also looking for similar help on this and would like to know whether you have any solution to this?

Comment: Just saw this question... This was from five years ago so I don't recall exactly how I did it, but I believed I ended up using Pandas to create a table for it.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do is use pandas. Something like:

```
import pandas as pd
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

def generate_html():
    read_file = pd.read_csv("example.csv")
    html_file = read_file.to_html()
    sendEmail(html_file)

def sendEmail(html_file):
    msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    msg['Subject'] = "Hello"
    msg['From'] = EmailFrom
    msg['To'] = EmailTo
    part = MIMEText(html_file, 'html')
    msg.attach(part)
    s = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com")
    s.sendmail(EmailFrom, EmailTo, msg.as_string())
    s.quit()
```

Comment: This doesn't work for some reason

Answer (score -2):

You might want to look into openpyxl https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/

Something like this might solve your problem:

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook

workbook = load_workbook(f)
worksheet = workbook.get_active_sheet()

html_data = """
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
        XLSX to HTML demo
        <title>
    <head>
    <body>
        <h3>
        XLSX to HTML demo
        <h3>
    <table>
"""

ws_range = worksheet.range('A1:H13')
for row in ws_range:
    html_data += "<tr>
    for cell in row:
        if cell.value is None:
            html_data += "<td> + ' ' + "<td>
        else:
            html_data += "<td> + str(cell.value) + "<td>
    html_data += "<tr>
html_data += "</table></body></html>
msg.attach(MIMEText(html_data))

with open(f, "rb") as fil:
    part = MIMEApplication(
        fil.read(),
        Name=basename(f)
    )
    part['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="{0}"'.format(basename(f))
    msg.attach(part)
```

Inspired by https://jugad2.blogspot.ch/2013/11/publish-microsoft-excel-xlsx-data-to.html?m=1

Comment: That converts it to an HTML file, but how do I put it in the body of the email?

Comment: aside from not directly answering the question, this answer is a "link only" answer, which is generally frowned upon here for several reasons...

Comment: I actually figured out how to send an HTML file on my own, but even following the code to convert the Excel file to HTML doesn't work.

Comment: So what is your solution?